# Issue with NWPathMonitor not relaying proper status when network connection is restored

Tags: swiftui

The following code properly handles when the internet connection drops but does not recognize when the internet connection is restored.  When it does come up the monitor sees that event but the path.status comes back as unsatisfied satisfied.  I would like to get the proper status when it's back up so I can properly proceed based on an accurate status.  Here is my code:

```
class NetworkStatus: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = NetworkStatus()

    private var monitor: NWPathMonitor?
    private var queue = DispatchQueue(label: "NetworkMonitor")

    @Published var isConnected: Bool = false

    private init() {
        monitor = NWPathMonitor()
        startMonitoring()
    }

    deinit {
        stopMonitoring()
    }
    
    func startMonitoring() {
        monitor?.pathUpdateHandler = { [weak self] path in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let status = path.status == .satisfied
                self?.isConnected = status
                print(">>> \(path.status)")
            }
        }

        monitor?.start(queue: queue)
    }

    func stopMonitoring() {
        monitor?.cancel()
        monitor = nil
    }
}
```

I expect that when the internet comes back up that it should show a status of satisfied but when the internet connectivity is restored it comes up as still unsatisfied.